# Purple Warning"Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior."

Tags: swiftui

Everyone,
When I build my app, there is a purple warning"Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior". And the most terrible thing is that the memory of my computer is eaten up little by little by the app and finally the computer has the warning"the memory is full, please close some programs to keep the computer functioning well."

The codes are as following:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class GetUidFromFirebase: ObservableObject{

@Published var userID: String = ""

    //get uid from firebase
    
    func GetUid() -> String {
            let UserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            userID = UserID ?? ""
            return userID
        }
    }
```

What's wrong with the codes? The purpose of them is to get uid from firebase and use it as user ID.

Answer (score 0):

Properties that are marked with @Published attribute must be accessed on the main thread. If you want to access the ID of the Firebase user then you can simply use the following link in your view.

```
guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
```

Comment: Hi, azamsharp, really thanks for your answer. Let me try it.